# Что за тулза - convert, и где её можно скачать?

Tags: javascript, изображения

Имеется следующая команда:

```
convert -background '#2f4f74' -fill white -gravity center -font "Symbolia" "pango:<span size='48000' ></span>" /images/out.png
```

которая сделает .png следующего вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это так называемая [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) которую можно скачать тут:

- [Windows Binary Release](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)
- [Unix Binary Release](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#unix)
- [Mac OS X Binary Release](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx)

Описание функции: [convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php)

А также ссылка на утилиты, на подобии конвертирования: [tools](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php)

Полезно прочесть перед использованием: [Basic Usage](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/)